# UIProgressView not updating from BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, backgroundworker

I'm in the process of porting my Xamarin.Android app to Xamarin.iOS, I can't make my progress bar update, where am I going wrong?

The values are set in `updateProgressBar()` correctly and `progressBarValue` in this example is set as 0.25 as expected, but the UIProgressView is not updated on the screen. `progressBar` is a `UIProgressView` on the storyboard.

```
public BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker { get; private set; }
private float progressBarValue { get; set; }

public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    startBackgroundWorker();
}

private void startBackgroundWorker()
{
    if (backgroundWorker == null || backgroundWorker.CancellationPending) backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        //do stuff  
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(25);
        //do stuff
    };
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => { //do stuff };
    backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => { updateProgressBar(e.ProgressPercentage); };
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void updateProgressBar(float v)
{
    if (v > 0){
        float value = v / 100;
        progressBarValue = progressBarValue + value;
        if (progressBarValue > 1) progressBarValue = 1;
        progressBar.Progress = progressBarValue;
    }
}
```

I also tried using `SetProgress(progressBarValue,true)`

```
private void updateProgressBar(float v)
{
    if (v > 0){
        float value = v / 100;
        progressBarValue = progressBarValue + value;
        if (progressBarValue > 1) progressBarValue = 1;
        progressBar.SetProgress(progressBarValue,true);
    }
}
```

and using `InvokeOnMainThread`

```
private void updateProgressBar(float v)
{
    if (v > 0){
        float value = v / 100;
        progressBarValue = progressBarValue + value;
        if (progressBarValue > 1) progressBarValue = 1;
        InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
            // manipulate UI controls
            progressBar.SetProgress(progressBarValue,true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the alternatives to down-voting? Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing. If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: I dont understand why you got down voted, you even posted your code +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, my problem was not related to my code in the question, or the question at all, I copied it into a new solution and it worked fine.

*Incase anyone finds this in the future and has made the same mistake:*

**My problem was that I had set `UIProgressView.TintColor` to an invalid value**  elsewhere in my code so the `ProgressView` was updating all along but it just wasn't visible.

```
progressView.TintColor = iOSHelpers.GetColor(GenericHelpers.colorPrimaryGreenRGBA);
```

iOSHelpers

```
public static UIColor GetColor(int[] rgba)
{
    if (rgba.Length == 4)
        return UIColor.FromRGBA(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);
    else return UIColor.Black;
}
```

GenericHelpers

```
public static int[] colorPrimaryGreenRGBA = { 140, 185, 50, 1 };
```

Once I had changed the`colorPrimaryGreenRGBA` values to floats and divided the RGB channels by 255 in the `GetColor` method it was then a visible color.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be sure your UI updates are running on the [main thread](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/)

```
InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
    // manipulate UI controls
    progressBar.SetProgress(progressBarValue,true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Jason, I tried this method but still with no luck. I had (wrongly) assumed that `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` would automatically be on the UI thread when initiated from within a `ViewController`

Comment: a. are you sure your bg methods are being called?  b.  the progressbar value is a Single, you are using a Float - there may be a conversion issue

Comment: .NET `System.Single` == C# `float` :-)